# React Native After Flatlist update constructor of items not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make a search filter with flatlist.
It works, but my problem is that after the flatlist update the constructor of the items are not called any more and I need to set a state in the constructor. What is the best way to handle this ?

flatlist

```js
<FlatList
            data={this.state.searchedArray}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            extraData={this.state}
            renderItem={this._renderItem} />
```

Handling searchfilter

```js
_handleChange(message) { 
     let text = message.toLowerCase();
     let searchedArray = [];

    console.log(searchedArray);
    if (text.length < 2) {
      return false;
    }
    // search trough json array
    searchedArray = this.state.data.filter(row => {
      if (row.symbol.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1 || row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1 || row.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }).map((row) => {
      return row;
    }); 

    this.setState({
      searchedArray: searchedArray
    });

  }
```

child component

```js
export default class SearchItem extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  const item = this.props.item;
    this.state = {
      image: item.symbol
    }
  }

  render() { 
    const item = this.props.item; 
    
    return (
      
        <View style={globalStyles.row}>
          <View style={[globalStyles.cell, globalStyles.primaryCell]}>

            <Image
              source={{ uri: this.state.image}}
              style={styles.image}
              blurRadius={0}
              onError={(a) => {
                this.setState({ image: 'question'})
            }}
                         />
                         </View>
                         </View>
        
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: ... and we should guess data structure, `_keyExtractor`, `_keyExtractor` ? constructor is usually caled once ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, but I already found a way to fix my "default image" problem.

```js
export default class SearchItem extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  const item = this.props.item;
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }
  }

  render() { 
    const item = this.props.item; 
    let symbol = (this.state.error) ? 'question' : item.symbol;
    
    return (
      
        <View style={globalStyles.row}>
          <View style={[globalStyles.cell, globalStyles.primaryCell]}>

            <Image
              source={{ uri: symbol}}
              style={styles.image}
              blurRadius={0}
              onError={(a) => {
                this.setState({ error: true})
            }} 
            />
           </View>
         </View>
        
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to SearchItem:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    if (this.state.image !== newProps.item.symbol) {
        this.setState({image: newProps.item.symbol})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use componentWillReceiveProps as well as extending your child component from react `Component` instead of `PureComponent`.